# I want to suggest the user some data while typing using JavaScript and PHP.. How can hat be?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

Uhh. let's an example...

This is the PHP code: *index.php* :->

```
<?php
// Starter tags
echo "<input name='name' value='name'> </input>";
?>
```

And this is the database table structure :

```
|------------|------------------|---------------------------------------|
| Name       |   Email          |          Description                  |
|------------|------------------|---------------------------------------|
|John Doe    | john@doe.com     |  John Doe is example person           |
|            |                  |                                       |
|Rishikesh   | risht@dot.com    |  Rishikesh is FnCEO of Pupoz          |
|------------|------------------|---------------------------------------|
```

How to write a jQuery code so that it asks PHP to execute a MySQL Query and give suggestions to select while typing. And that input box should be on the PHP page. Please add your own name if you can and I will try that later on. Thanks if you can help me.

I have some doubts. And will ask the questions later.

Answer (score 6):

use Jquery UI AutoComplete, it can be used with Remote datasource, An Array of data. it has many options such as modal, styles. [JqueryAutocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

```
<div id="SomeID"> <input type="text" id="SomeTextID"/></div>
```

Jquery.

```
$(function(){

$( "#SomeTextID" ).autocomplete({
            source: "YourPhpPage.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
```

});

see Demo : [JSFiddle AutoCompleter](http://jsfiddle.net/XftCe/1/)